# CouchDB Replication to Android ... for Android Applications, or Android Browser or?

Tags: android, couchdb, replication

My goal is to replicate my CouchDB to Android to allow offline access & reduced latency.

- I watched this video: 
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RdcKWYGqig

One fundamental point I don't get is:

- Does CouchDB replication work only
  for Android Applications?
- Or, can it work for a web application
  running in the Android browser (this
  is what I am shooting for)? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would need to install the CouchDB software on the Android device in order to get it to work.

Once that is installed, the user can visit your app via the browser at http://localhost:5984/path/to/my/app

You could create one of those bookmarks that looks like an app, and point it to the local couch url.

Chris

Comment: +1. I thought there was an internal Android Java API but I'm glad to hear it's just a couch if you connect over HTTP.

Comment: For users who do not install CouchDB on Android, what is the best practices way of giving them offline access to my CouchDB data (using Node.js)? Here's my guess: When the user is online, read CouchDB data and output JS object literal listing the data.  Store JS object literal in app cache. Offline visitor will then be able to get data from app cache.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can create browser based applications.

Either try creating a couchapp and loading it with the browserview in android or club it with something like Sencha to wrap it around and making it a hybrid native web app!

If you know how to create couchapps, then it should be pretty straight forward, else, take a look into how to create  simple couchapps. Ofcourse, i'm going under the assumption that you already know a bit of Android!